# converting a python string to a variable

Tags: python-3.x, string, numpy, indexing

I have read almost every similar question but none of them seems to solve my current problem.

In my python code, I am importing a string from my bashrc and in the following, I am defining the same name as a variable to index my dictionary. Here is the simple example

```
obs = os.environ['obs']
>> obs = 'id_0123'

id_0123 = numpy.where(position1 == 456)
>> position1[id_0123] = 456
>> position2[id_0123] = 789
```

But of course, when I do `positions[obs]`, it throws an error since it is a string rather than an index (`numpy.int64`). So I have tried to look for a solution to convert my string into a variable but all solution suggesting to either convert into a dictionary or something else and assign the string to an integer, But I can not do that since my string is dynamic and will constantly change. In the end, I am going to have about 50 variables and I need to check the current obs corresponding to which variable, so I could use it as indices to access the parameters.

Edit:

Position1 and Position 2 are just bumpy arrays, so depending on the output of os.environ (which is 'id_0123' in this particular case), they will print an array element. So I can not assign 'id_0123' another string or number since I am using that exact name as a variable.

The logic is that there are many different arrays, I want to use the output of os.environ as an input to access the element of these arrays.

Comment: What's `position1'?

Comment: Its an array. So depending on the output of os.environ ('id_0123') the arrays are going to print different elements of that array!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that (almost) everything is a dictionary in Python to create storage container that you index with `obs`:

```
container = lambda:None

container.id_0123 = ...

...

print(positions[container.__dict__[obs]])
```

Alternatively, you can use `globals()` or `locals()` to achieve the desired behavior:

```
import numpy
import os
def environment_to_variable(environment_key='obs', variable_values=globals()):
    # Get the name of the variable we want to reference from the bash environment
    variable_name = os.environ[environment_key]
    # Grab the variable value that matches the named variable from the environment. Variable you want to reference must be visible in the global namespace by default.
    variable_value = variable_values[variable_name]
    return variable_value

positions = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
id_0123 = 2 # could use numpy.where here
id_0456 = 4

index = environment_to_variable(variable_values=locals())

print(positions[index])
```

If you place this in a file called `a.py`, you can observe the following:

```
$ obs="id_0123" python ./a.py
5
$ obs="id_0456" python ./a.py
11
```

This allows you to index the array differently at runtime, which is what it seems like your intention is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But again this is not helpful in my case. Please see the comment I have left above.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make it all that clear what your intent is, but here's my reading on it: you have a string, let's call it `foo`, that gets exported into the system environment. What you want is to have a python variable with that same name created, eg `foo = os.environ("foo")`, is that correct? If so, and you also do not want to use the container wrapper (really just a prefix), you could achieve this using `locals()` or `globals()`, though that's going to make future maintenance difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a dictionary instead, this would work.

```
obs = 'id_0123'
my_dict = {obs: 'Tester'}
print (my_dict [obs])
print (my_dict ['id_0123'])
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was referring to. I can assign my string ('id_0123') another random string because I am using the same exact string name as a variable to indice my arrays. There is gonna be 50 different strings that gonna come from my bash and each one of them are used as a variable. The logic is depending on what the string (variable), they python gonna print another output.